Linq2Db Firebird - violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint although in transaction
I have a department tree hierarchy in firebird I do CRUD on. At least I would like to. Using Linq2Db and the firebird provider I cannot insert into the table without getting the error: violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint. The problem is I began a transaction. And that's what transactions are for, to (among other things) temporarily disable the FK checks.
I tried both the .Net TransactionScope and the method LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection.BeginTransactionAsync. I tried every System.Data.IsolationLevel. But I keep getting these errors.
How to make Linq2Db transactions work

I wonder where did you get a strange idea about "disabling FK checks"? Foreign Key constraints in Firebird are intermediate, deferred constraints are not implemented.

@user13964273 I assume you meant "immediate".

@MarkRotteveel Yes. These English words are all soooo much similar...

The behaviour you're expecting only applies to "deferred" constraints, which are checked at commit time. However, all constraints in Firebird are immediate constraints (a.k.a. non-deferrable), which means they are checked immediately when you perform an operation.
In other words, you need to order your operations in such a way that they do not violate the constraints. That is, insert the parent record before a child record.
